# Using mills() in place of delay() on relays not getting solid switch over

Tags: relay, nrf24l01+, millis, timing

I know I should post some code that maybe cleaner but really I am just in need of a answer to a problem I seem to run into a lot when using `mills()` in place of `delay()`, whilst making a Christmas light display.

Maybe it's me but I do not get contestant switching over of mechanical relays when I try to use `mills()` timing to switch relays . I seems like the code trips the relay then untrips the relay in milliseconds and not really latching the relay like I get with `delay()`. Is this the nature of the `mills()` choice where the output is triggered every cycle  but is not truly an output during the whole process cycle?  Now if this is true, then is there a good way to latch a relay with out using a `delay()`?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
//


  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  unsigned long previousMillis = millis();
  int interval_on = 2000; //  Length of time On

  unsigned long currentMillis_off = millis();
  unsigned long previousMillis_off ;
  int interval_off = 2000; // length of time off

//
#define button 4
int Lite_1=0;


RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN

const byte address[6] = "00001";
boolean buttonState = 0;

unsigned long time;

void setup() {
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.stopListening();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();        // must be in loop
   unsigned long currentMillis_off = millis();  // Must be in loop
  //                             const char text[] = "Hello World";
 //                       radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
  //delay(1000);

   //                       delay(5); Removed to help in timing
   //                       radio.stopListening(); removeded to help in timing 
   // Lite_1 = 1;
    radio.write(&Lite_1, sizeof(Lite_1));
  //    delay(1000);
 //   Lite_1 = 0 ;
 // radio.write(&Lite_1, sizeof(Lite_1));
  // delay(250);



  if (Lite_1 == 0 && currentMillis - previousMillis > interval_off) 
    {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    previousMillis + 10;
    previousMillis_off = currentMillis_off  ;
    Lite_1 = 1;
    Serial.println(currentMillis);    //prints time since program started
      }
    //Debug
  // Serial.print("Time: ");
 // time = millis();

 // Serial.println(time);    //prints time since program started
//  Serial.println(currentMillis);    //prints time since program started
//  Serial.println(previousMillis);    //prints time since program started
//  Serial.println(previousMillis_off);    //prints time since program started
 // Serial.println(currentMillis_off);    //prints time since program started
  //delay(250);     


    if (Lite_1==1 && currentMillis_off - previousMillis_off > interval_on) 
       {
    previousMillis_off = currentMillis_off;
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    previousMillis + 10;
    Lite_1 = 0;
    Serial.print("OFF: ");
    Serial.println(previousMillis_off);    //prints time since program started
    }

  }
```

Comment: Format your code correctly by editing your question,selecting the code and click the `{}` button in the editors toolbar or press Ctrl+k on the keyboard.

Comment: At which part of the code do you switch the relays? I don't see any digitalWrite() or similar, which could be used to switch something. Only Serial output.

Comment: What should it do? Is it to turn on the relay half a second with 2 seconds in between? Is that continuous or is that triggered by an event? Please add the extra information to your question.

Comment: Ron, you can't answer comments until you register to SE. Check your email.

Comment: Can you explain the role of nrf24L01 in this code?  There may be other ways to achieve the functionality that you need.

Comment: "role of nrf24L01"  is a Wifi  device  code  as I under stand it.

Comment: The program opens a Network connecition to another arauduino on the network

Comment: No digital write since it is just telling the other arduino to do the digirtal Write function at Lite_1 = 1

Answer (score -1):

Something like this works.

```
  unsigned long currentMillis;
  unsigned long previousMillis;
  unsigned long nextEventTime;

  unsigned long interval_on  = 2000;        // length of time On
  unsigned long interval_off = 2000;        // length of time off

  bool Lite_1;

  void setup() {

    previousMillis = millis();

    Lite_1 = false;                                     // start at the begining of the off cycle
    nextEventTime = previousMillis + interval_off;      // start at the begining of the off cycle

    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.print("starting in OFF cycle\t");
    Serial.println(previousMillis);
  }

  void loop() {

    if (millis() > nextEventTime) {                     // check the interval before doing any other checks

    currentMillis = millis();

    if (Lite_1) {

      nextEventTime = currentMillis + interval_off;     // do the calculation only once
      Serial.print("OFF:\t");

    } else {

      nextEventTime = currentMillis + interval_on;
      Serial.print("ON:\t");
    }

    Lite_1 = !Lite_1;                           // invert value
    Serial.println(currentMillis);              // prints time since program started
    }
  }
```

Comment: When a value is added to a value from millis, and then compared to millis, that causes a rollover problem. Always subtract a previous millis from the current millis.

Comment: Then how would I do this math if I can not add to the Millis()?

Comment: I believe the way to make that work is `nextEventTime - currentMillis > interval_of`.  Informally speaking, doing that subtraction instead of an addition guarantees that we are going to be doing the inequality with a small number, rather than a number that's potentially large enough to roll over when `interval_off` is added to it.

Comment: Firstly, what is the purpose of declaring all variables as global ones? Secondly, `if (millis() > nextEventTime)` - this will not work properly around the moment of `millis()` rollover.